# how to use string.at to assign value to it

Tags: c++, string

The goal of my program is to output a new password from a string that the user input. The problem that I encountered is to assign value based on the user input and I cannot make the letter equal to a number. I want to avoid using "char" to assign it.

Eg: when user input one letter such as `b`, it should have the numeric value of `2` and it would print out `2`. Or, an user input `cab`, this would print out `312`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

string password; 
cin >> password;
password.at()

while (password != "\n")

if (password == a || password == A)
{
    password = 1;
}
else if (password == b || password == B)
{
    password = 2;
}
else if (password == c || password == C)
{
    password = 3;
}

cout << password;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (password != "\n")` is unlikely to be evaluated to `true`, rather check  for `!password.empty()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++11 one could use:

```
for (auto const & char: password) {
  switch (char) {
    case 'a': case 'A': std::cout << '1'; break;
    case 'b': case 'B': std::cout << '2'; break;
    case 'c': case 'C': std::cout << '3'; break;
    default: /* Do something else */ break;
  };
}
```

Or in earlier versions of C++:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0u; i < password.size(); ++i) {
  switch (password[i]) {
    case 'a': case 'A': std::cout << '1'; break;
    case 'b': case 'B': std::cout << '2'; break;
    case 'c': case 'C': std::cout << '3'; break;
    default: /* Do something else */ break;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string password;

    if (std::getline(std::cin, password))
    {
        for (const auto character : password)
        {
            if (std::isalpha(character))
            {
                const auto integral_value =
                    static_cast<int>(std::tolower(character) - 'a') + 1;
                std::cout << integral_value;
            }
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```